# Laravel: save() does not save all fields

Tags: php, laravel, save

i have another problem with Laravel 5.2. I have one form which has several input fields, but not all of them are stored in the database (neither by store() or update() ).

They way i do it:

CityController in store():

```
$id = $this->country->create(['status' => 1] + $request->only('code', 'currency_id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'timezone', 'dam_date'))->id;
```

Here it does save the data in the DB, except the fields: status, timezone and dam_date.

i have made an output of the $request. There are values. If i made a country object and give him the parameters and then save it, it works.

The same problem i have also in the update() function:

```
$country->fill($request->only('code', 'currency_id', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'timezone', 'dam_date'))->save();
```

again it does not save the timezone and the dam_date.

I have added both fields later to the table. Maybe this can help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you add `status`, `timezone` and `dam_date` fileds to `fillable` array?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: debuging for hours what is wrong until I saw your answer. thank you